# Decode XML with Swift & XMLCoder

Tags: swift, xml, decode

I can successfully decode an XML file with XMLCoder, but the XML files I need to handle will all have a section of XML that I don't want to actually decode - rather I need to store that as a String.  I know the element name that will contain this section, but when I try to decode the file, this section is always just empty instead of containing the existing XML as a String.

So if my XML is this:

```
<RootElement>
    <Track>
        <Section>
            <Machines>
                <MachineOne>
                   ....
                </MachineOne>
            </Machines>
        <Section>
    </Track>
</RootElement>
```

I want to decode down to the Machines node and store everything inside the Machines class as a String.

```
class RootElement: Codable {
    var track:Track?

...
}

class Track: Codable {
    var section: Section?
...
}

class Section: Codable {
    var machines: Machines?
....
}

class Machines: Codable {
    var internalMachines: String?
...
}
```

In this scenario, my decoder gets down to Machines, but its internalMachines value is empty.

I'm pretty new to Swift.  Any pointers are much appreciated.

https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder

Thanks.

Comment: If you have an issue with your code then post that code here in your question and not as a link.

Comment: Sorry, the link is only to the library that I'm using for decoding.  The pertinent code is above.

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood a little but this means that only people how knows this library  can help you since it's there where it all happens.